# Creating Soap Request WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

Im new in soap request, my client send me sample request format but he told me that I was'nt able to pass the parameter correctly. I dont know if my codes are the problem, I paste the sample request and my code

Thanks

here is the sample request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:card="http://placeholder/CARD">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <card:CardPrinting>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <WebRequestCommon>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <company></company>
            <password></password>
            <userName>CARDPRINTING</userName>
         </WebRequestCommon>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <PSSLAICARDPRINTINGType>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <enquiryInputCollection>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <columnName>CUSTOMER.CODE</columnName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <criteriaValue>100115</criteriaValue>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <operand>EQ</operand>
            </enquiryInputCollection>
         </PSSLAICARDPRINTINGType>
      </card:CardPrinting>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my code is

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://placeholder/CARD/services?wsdl');
$params = array(
    'WebRequestCommon'=>array(
        'company'=>'',
        'password'=>'123456',
        'userName'=>'TAMIZH4'
    ),
    'PSSLAICARDPRINTINGType'=>array(
        'enquiryInputCollection'=>array(
            'columnName'=>'CUSTOMER.CODE',
            'criteriaValue'=>'100115',
            'operand'=>'EQ'
        )
    )
);
$students = $client->CardPrinting($params);
```

Comment: And what request does your code produce? You can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php).

Comment: Nothing the page is still loading its about 3mins now.

Comment: Its stop now no output when I print_r();

Comment: the return of __getLastRequest(); is 123456TAMIZH4

Comment: Ok, try to print that like this: `echo "<pre>" . htmlentities( print_r( $client->__getLastRequest(), 1 ) ) . "</pre>";`, so you can see the XML tags better.

Comment: the output is like this I dont know why the second parameter is invalid

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://temenos.com/CARD”>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:CardPrinting>
   <WebRequestCommon>
    <company></company>
    <password>123456</password>
    <userName>TAMIZH4</userName>
   </WebRequestCommon>
  </ns1:CardPrinting>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: I don't see a difference either; the only difference is the namespace prefixes, but they do not matter. You can also print the [__getLastresponse](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php), see if there's any error messages in there.

Comment: My client give me wrong request sample that is why the return was wrong. I ask him a another sample and I follow it and now the return is right. thanks for the help the getLastRequest gave me more idea :)).